# Save looping values in one variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to save my loops values into a variable.

This is how I am looping:

```
 foreach ($apartment AS $apt) {

                $userApt = $area->getApartments()->get($apt)->getApartment();
                echo $userApt . "<br>";
}
```

Now here the value can be 0 to 100 like, "Hello Apartment.com", "my apartment.com", "my fav apartment.com", etc

Now my question is, how can I save to all values into one variable, so when I call that function I can get all those values at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you want to save the values in a way that would let you iterate through them again later :

```
$userApt = array();
foreach ($appartment as $apt) {
    $userApt[] = 
}

... (later in code)

foreach($userApt as $apt) {
    echo $apt.'<br />';
}

// OR

echo implode('<br />', $userApt);
```

Comment: implode('<br />', $userApt); this is working fine with me, but still there is a tiny problem, when i am getting the values it is not separating by any comma like (,) it is coming like www.google.comwww.youtube.com

Comment: @ChristoferHansen You get the values as one big line, without new lines?? When you use that implode fucntion? thats very strange.